# Simple transistor circuit with unconnected gate pin acts strangely

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, ground

My brother and I were playing around with some new transistors we ordered (2n7000 n-channel MOSFETs), trying to make a simple switching circuit: connect a switch, LED turns on; open the switch, LED turns off. [Here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0AR+512+240+512+176+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+512+336+512+400+0+330%0Af+464+320+512+320+0+1.5%0Aw+512+240+512+304+0%0Aw+432+240+512+240+0%0Aw+432+240+432+272+0%0Aw+432+304+432+320+0%0Aw+432+320+464+320+0%0Ax+359+294+425+297+0+24+switch%0A162+512+400+512+464+1+2.1024259+1+0+0%0Ag+512+464+512+480+0%0As+432+272+432+304+0+0+false%0A)'s a link to the circuit we were attempting to make.

[image]
[Here](https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/UQGZcewGfAf85emDPhl3jw7yjONtAfpT/IMG_0827.JPG)'s a picture of what we implemented in a breadboard. There's one difference from the above circuit: the switch is not actually complete. We just have a single wire connected to the n-MOSFET's gate. So [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0AR+512+240+512+176+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+512+336+512+400+0+330%0Af+464+320+512+320+0+1.5%0Aw+512+240+512+304+0%0Aw+400+320+464+320+0%0Ax+366+326+392+329+0+24+??%0A162+512+400+512+464+1+2.1024259+1+0+0%0Ag+512+464+512+480+0%0A) is what we actually have in the breadboard.

As far as we can tell, from our limited electrical engineering experience, the LED should never be on, since there is no connection from the +5V power to the transistor's gate; the transistor should not let any current through. However, there were two interesting things: first, the LED turned on as soon as we powered on the circuit, even before we connected the transistor's gate to power. Also, whenever we touch/tap the wire connected to the gate (labeled by "??" in the circuit), the LED randomly switches between three different levels of brightness (on, medium, off), and will even "stick" at a brightness setting, even between power cycles of the entire circuit. The single transistor appears to act as a flip-flop!

So, the question is: why does touching the unconnected wire change the LED's state?

And, secondarily, how is the LED on, even if the transistor has no voltage source attached to the gate?

Comment: _"The single transistor appears to act as a flip-flop!"_ - Actually, it acts more like a DRAM cell ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A floating gate has a voltage. Any wire has a voltage. Until you put it in reference to something else, that voltage can be anything. Don't expect it to be 0V or any other known voltage.

That gate also has a capacitance. Your body is a capacitance. Every time you touch that gate, you're connecting two capacitors and a charge balance will occur. This will alter the voltage on the gate. Ergo, you've created a simple transistor capacitor memory scheme not terribly different than DRAM. Pretty nifty huh?

I'm surprised a little that the brightness remains the same between power cycles, but maybe that's attributable to having a high quality mosfet with a high gate impedance?

Lastly, although this is a great lesson, don't design a circuit like this with a floating node expecting it to be a specific voltage.

Comment: I am the brother that @feralin spoke of, so I feel qualified to explain: we actually did originally have a switch (as shown by the first circuit linked in the question) consisting of two wires that we could simply touch to each other. However, touching them did not seem to do anything (even though that completed a connection from +5V to the gate). At that point, we decided to experiment and got to the current situtation. So can you explain why, even with a switch, the transistor was not working as we expected?

Comment: @Jashaszun You'll have to describe it a little clearer. You're saying when the switch was closed, the transistor did not light?

Comment: I'm saying that whether or not the switch was closed, the transistor *did* light and exhibit the strange effects that we described in the question.

Comment: @Jashaszun That sounds like your transistor is partially blown OR you have the transistor in backwards (source and drain flipped). If it was backwards, it's possible it is partially or fully blown now too.

Comment: Hmm... I'll go test it right now. So I should just flip the transistor, put the switch back in, and test?

Comment: @Jashaszun yup. And make sure that resistor is in place. And to prevent further blown transistors, make sure your gate also has a resistor on it.

Comment: Alright, [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.200277308269968+50+5+43%0AR+512+240+512+176+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+512+304+512+368+0+330%0Af+464+384+512+384+0+1.5%0Aw+512+240+512+304+0%0Aw+432+240+512+240+0%0Aw+432+240+432+272+0%0Aw+432+304+432+320+0%0Aw+432+384+464+384+0%0Ax+359+294+425+297+0+24+switch%0A162+512+400+512+464+1+2.1024259+1+0+0%0Ag+512+464+512+480+0%0As+432+272+432+304+0+0+false%0Ar+432+384+432+464+0+330%0Aw+432+320+432+384+0%0Aw+432+464+512+464+0%0A) is what we have now. We now have a pulldown on the gate wire.

Comment: However, we originally had a 1M resistor for the pulldown there, which Falstad says should work. In our circuit, when we had the 1M pulldown, the LED was either bright or medium. With 330 as the pulldown, it worked perfectly. Can you explain why 1M does not work? Also, in Falstad our circuit works even without the pulldown, while in real life it does not. Can you explain that too? Sorry if there are way too many questions here...

Comment: @Jashaszun If you look at the spec sheet: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N7000.pdf
 you'll see that the Rgs resistance is <=1Mohm which means that if you have 1M pulldown resistor, you actually create a voltage divider putting 1/2 of Vdd at your gate through the internal gate resistance. That means your transistor would always be on. Basically, your gate inherently has a resistor internally that connects to the source (and drain) that's less than 1Mohm. If your external resistors are anywhere near that, things are going to behave weird.

Comment: Thanks a ton horta! I believe that solves all of our problems and answers all of our questions. As you can tell, we're pretty new to this stuff, but I hope we'll learn quickly!

Comment: @Jashaszun no worries. Glad to be of help. Playing/practicing/experimenting is the fastest/best way to learn so keep it up!

Comment: @Jashaszun Oh I forgot to answer the question of why it works in Falstad but not in real life. That's because it's a simulator, and when the switch is off, the simulator assumes that a node not connected to anything is 0 volts. In real life, as my answer explains, that's just not the case. Better simulators would let you know that you have a floating voltage in your circuit rather than assume it goes to 0V.

Comment: @horta The value of Rgs <= 1 Mohm that you quote is NOT a FET parameter - it is a condition applied to the FET while V_DGR is tested. It is saying that to achieve the maximu V_DGR of 60V, you must have no more than 1 MOhm from gate to source. 
MOSFET internal RGS is very very large - leakage across the gate oxide. | The effect you talk about is not caused by the FET acting as a resistive divider component.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon That's good to know. Then it's either a defective/failed part or the breadboard capacitance + gate capacitance would be causing the issue would be my best guess. It still doesn't seem to be large enough to cause the issues the OP posted about though.